# {% paginate %} Tag issue, no prevUrl / nextUrl Data

Tags: craft3, pagination

I have problem with the `{% paginate%}` tag.

Setting:

- Craft CMS 3.0.18
- Channel with 3 Entries -> handle "newsBlog"

`{% paginate craft.entries.section('newsBlog') as pageInfo, pageEntries %}`

When i open the second Entry in the News-Channel i get following values

- `pageInfo.total`: 3
- `pageInfo.currentPage`: 1 -> Why?
- `pageInfo.nextUrl`: empty -> Why?
- `pageInfo.prevUrl`: empty -> Why?

I did a lot of Craft 2 projects without pagination problems.

What did I do wrong? Thx for help!

Answer (score 5):

You need to set a `limit` on your element query, so Craft knows how many entries you want per page:

```
{% paginate craft.entries.section('newsBlog').limit(1) as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
```

If you *don't* set a limit, `{% paginate %}` will return a single page with *all* entries, because the default value for `limit` in Craft 3 is `null` (in Craft 2, the default was `100`).

Comment: thx for answer!!